# Jquery Change CSS Background Color

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element with the id '**center-layout**' - within this is an `<li>` that has no id or class assigned.

It does have background-color set.  How would I dynamically change the background color of this li using jquery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using:

```
$('#center-layout li').css("background-color", "newcolor");
```

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't work out how to add the li to that !

Comment: @JeffVader: glad it helps :)